# Smarty: extract value from array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have this array in variable **$attributesCombinations**:

```
->value = Array (16)
  0 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "7392"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "90_x_42_3_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft1"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  1 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "25310"
    id_attribute_group => "12"
    attribute => "farfalle_1"
    group => "modello"
    reference => "fft1"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  2 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "16548"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "99_6_x_67_5_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft1"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  3 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "6299"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "39_5_x_30_9_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft2"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  4 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "25311"
    id_attribute_group => "12"
    attribute => "farfalle_2"
    group => "modello"
    reference => "fft2"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  5 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "7392"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "90_x_42_3_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft2"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  6 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "16548"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "99_6_x_67_5_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft2"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  7 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "6299"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "39_5_x_30_9_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft3"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  8 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "25312"
    id_attribute_group => "12"
    attribute => "farfalle_3"
    group => "modello"
    reference => "fft3"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  9 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "7392"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "90_x_42_3_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft3"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  10 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "16548"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "99_6_x_67_5_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft3"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  11 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "6299"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "39_5_x_30_9_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft4"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  12 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "25313"
    id_attribute_group => "12"
    attribute => "farfalle_4"
    group => "modello"
    reference => "fft4"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  13 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "7392"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "90_x_42_3_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft4"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  14 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "16548"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "99_6_x_67_5_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft4"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
  15 => Array (8)
    id_attribute => "6299"
    id_attribute_group => "4"
    attribute => "39_5_x_30_9_cm_"
    group => "dimensioni"
    reference => "fft1"
    ean13 => ""
    isbn => ""
    upc => ""
->nocache = false
->scope = "file:catalog/_partials/product-varian..."
```

I want to extract the **'reference'** value for each **'group'** named **'modello'** I tried with the following:

```
{foreach from=$attributesCombinations item=row}
   {if $row.group|stristr:'modello'}{$row.reference}{/if}
{/foreach}
```

with the following result:

`fft1fft2fft3fft4fft1fft2fft3fft4fft1fft2fft3fft4fft1fft2fft3fft4`

All references are duplicated for each combination, I would just like to extract 'reference' value that has the group named 'modello' How can be done ?

Expected result:

fft1fft2fft3fft4

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
foreach from=$attributesCombinations item=row}
   {if $row.group eq 'modello'}{$row.reference}{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: same result, no difference.